# An Exercise in Complex Analysis (integrals)

Tags: complex-analysis

1. Let $z_0\in D(0,1)$ and $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\bar{D}(z_0,\varepsilon)\subset D(0,1)$. Show that for every $t\in [0,1]$ it holds $|1-zt|\geq 1-\varepsilon -|z_0|>0$ (I proove it by applying Inverse Triangle Inequality)
2. Let $g\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ continuous. By using (1) show that for $z_0\in D(0,1)$ the function $G(z)=\int_0^1 \dfrac{g(t)}{(1-zt)(1-z_0t)} dt, \ z\in D(0,1)$ is well-defined and continuous at $z_0$ (I poove it by using Sequences).
3. Let $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. By using (2) show that function $H(z)=\int_0^1\dfrac{f(t)}{1-zt} dt, \ z\in D(0,1)$ is holomorphic and then find its complex derivative on $D(0,1)$.

My only question is how to solve (3). My try: Let $z_0\in D(0,1)$ and then I calculate $\dfrac{H(z)-H(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\int_0^1 \dfrac{tf(t)}{(1-zt)(1-z_0t)},$ for $z_0\neq z\in D(0,1)$. Somehow I must apply (2) but I cannot see it. Any Help please? Thanks

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, $t\mapsto tf(t)$ is also continuous. Then you can use 2. to conclude that $G$ (with $g(t) = tf(t)$) is continuous at $z_0$, hence the derivative $H'(z_0)$ exists for every $z_0\in D(0,1)$ and is equal to $G(z_0)$.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the answer is right in front of us!!